# Does IP-XACT's register field can have reset field?

Tags: xml, ip-xact

I'm trying to understand IP-XACT from https://www.accellera.org/images/downloads/standards/ip-xact/IP-XACT_User_Guide_2018-02-16.pdf.

IP-XACT explains that
[image: ![enter image description here]

And I found reference XML component map from Cadence as the below,
[image]

As you can see the above xml tree, reset invoked in ns1:register, But there is no any kind of explanation about reset in register field.

Can I use reset element under register element?